# Lodash pickAs - pick properties from object into new one under different keys

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there any way how to pick property from object into new object under different key?

E.g.:

```
// pseudo
let a = {prop1: 'a', prop2: 'b', prop3: 'c'}
_.pickAs(a, {prop1: 'first', prop3: 'second'}
// {first: 'a', second: 'c'}
```

Comment: Do you really need lodash for this? Vanilla JS wouldn't do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to create a `pickAs()` method:

```js
const a = {prop1: 'a', prop2: 'b', prop3: 'c'}

const pickAs = (obj, props) => 
  Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    if(k in props) r[props[k]] = v;
  
    return r;
  }, {});
  
const result = pickAs(a, {prop1: 'first', prop3: 'second'});
console.log(result) // {first: 'a', second: 'c'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash `_.mapKeys` method to rename the keys after you've picked them from the object. As far as I know there's no method to do both at the same time, but this works quite well:

```js
const a = {prop1: 'a', prop2: 'b', prop3: 'c'}

const result = _.mapKeys(_.pick(a, ["prop1", "prop3"]), (v, k) => k.endsWith("1") ? "first" : "second");
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You'll want to replace the `mapKeys` second argument with a function that fits your actual use case. That function is invoked with two arguments: the value and the key, and should return the new key that you want.